# How to present a modal on Apple watch from the extension delegate

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am updating the watch kit support of a client app for Watch OS 2.0.

The iOS app adds a custom action to local notifications that cause the watch to display a custom button if the phone is locked when the local notification fires.

When the user taps the button, the extension delegate sends a message to the phone using the `WCSession` `sendMessage:replyHandler:` method.

If the phone is still locked when the user taps the action's button, I would like to display a message to the user saying "please unlock your phone to " (details about "the stuff" are not important.)

However, in WatchKit 2.0, the Extension delegate is a separate critter from interface controllers, and runs on the watch.

All the methods I can find that display an interface controller, like  `presentAlertControllerWithTitle:message:preferredStyle:actions:` are methods of WKInterfaceController.

How do I display a new interface controller from the Extension delegate? I'm trying to figure this out from the docs (and google searching) but so far I've struck out, despite a fairly extensive search.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when trying to show UI in response to extension delegate messages.

You can get the root controller through `[[WKExtension sharedExtension] rootInterfaceController]` but there isn't any way to walk the controller hierarchy from the root controller so it isn't really useful if you have other controllers pushed/presented.

I ended up creating a `WKInterfaceController` subclass that subscribes to `NSNotificationCenter` on `didAppear` and unsubscribes on `willDisappear` which theoretically should mean only one controller (the visible one) would be listening at a time, though I didn't really test it thoroughly enough to guarantee there wasn't any weird corner cases.

The extension delegate sends a notification when receiving a local or remote notification and the notification callback in the interface controller just calls `presentAlertControllerWithTitle:...` and all my interface controllers descend from that subclass.

I was trying to show an alert when receiving a remote notification while the watch app was open and not in response to the app opening from a notification action though.  I'm not sure what order the interface controller `didAppear` and the extension delegate `handleActionWithIdentifier` methods would get called in so you may not have any interface controllers listening to the notification when handling the action.  If `handleAction...` gets called first then you might have to add some logic to the interface controller on `didAppear` to check if there was some pending notification to be shown and have it show it then.

Comment: dan, thanks for your response and suggestions. The UI on this app is DIRT simple. I think I might be able to get away with always using the root view controller. This seems like a gap in the API to me. Surely we're not the only ones who need to do this?